# Is there a way to loop through a matrix/df in R to create an adjacency matrix?

Tags: r, loops, apply

I am trying to loop through 53 rows in a data.frame and create an adjacency matrix with the results. However, my efforts continue to be stalled by the fact that the loop will not run correctly.

I have tried to create matches as well as applying numerous `count()` functions, without success.

MRE: (In truth, the data is a lot larger so my unique search is actually 217k elements)

```r
df1<-data.frame(col1=c(12345,123456,1234567,12345678),
col2=c(54321,54432,12345,76543),
col3=c(11234,12234,1234567,123345),
col4=c(54321,54432,12345,76543))

search<-c(12345,1234567,75643,54432)
```

I would like to loop through each row and update a new matrix/df where the count per number in [search] would be the output.

Ex:

df2

```
        12345     1234567    75643    54432
row1    TRUE       TRUE      FALSE    FALSE
row2    FALSE      FALSE     TRUE      TRUE
row3    TRUE       TRUE      FALSE    FALSE
row4    TRUE       FALSE     TRUE     TRUE
```

Comment: Just a doubt,  is the expected output `df2` ?

Comment: indeed it is. although, probably going to be massive. Once I figure this out, I am going to provide a weight to the variables (ids in 'search' vector). E.g. '12345' and '1234567' occur n_times within the df.  Basically a 'From' 'To' edgelist with 'From' being the unique id (search) and 'To' being the shared id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it is unclear how your counts are derived as there might even be a typo (`75643 != 76543`) or if you are running by rows or columns, consider a nested `sapply` and `apply` solution for both margins:

**By Row**

```
search <- c(12345, 1234567, 76543, 54432)                                # ADJUSTED TYPO    
mat <- sapply(search, function(s) apply(df1, 1, function(x) s %in% x))   # 1 FOR ROW MARGIN

colnames(mat) <- search
rownames(mat) <- paste0("row", seq(nrow(df1)))

mat
#      12345 1234567 76543 54432
# row1  TRUE   FALSE FALSE FALSE
# row2 FALSE   FALSE FALSE  TRUE
# row3  TRUE    TRUE FALSE FALSE
# row4 FALSE   FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

**By Column**

```
search <- c(12345, 1234567, 76543, 54432)                                # ADJUSTED TYPO
mat <- sapply(search, function(s) apply(df1, 2, function(x) s %in% x))   # 2 FOR COL MARGIN

colnames(mat) <- search
rownames(mat) <- paste0("col", seq(ncol(df1)))

mat
#      12345 1234567 76543 54432
# col1  TRUE    TRUE FALSE FALSE
# col2  TRUE   FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
# col3 FALSE    TRUE FALSE FALSE
# col4  TRUE   FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

[Rextester demo](https://rextester.com/LFWUPH2104)

Comment: Parfait, this is exacly what I was looking for. However - any idea if we can run apply with dplyr to get a weight count ? The matrix is massive (10 obs = 25mb) and I have 800...so thats gonna add up haha. I am hoping I can loop in a count function to get the number of times numbers appear together in a column....something like [$Freq... 12345:1234567 (5)  | 12345|76543 (2) etc.]. *May help in contolling the RAM overkill and its is what the endstate is anyway

Comment: Great. Glad to help. The weighting question should be asked on a different post as you will need to clearly describe and show what you mean with earnest attempt at solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should check the `tf (term frequency) algorithm` for text mining. Here an interesting approach for your example using the `library(quanteda)` to create the matrix with the counts. Then you can do the searches you feel like based on counts:

```
library("tibble")
library("quanteda")


df1<-data.frame(col1=c(12345,123456,1234567,12345678),
                col2=c(54321,54432,12345,76543),
                col3=c(11234,12234,1234567,123345),
                col4=c(54321,54432,12345,76543))
df2<-apply(df1,2,paste, collapse = " ") # Passing it to string format
DocTerm <- quanteda::dfm(df2)
DocTerm

Document-feature matrix of: 4 documents, 10 features (60.0% sparse).
4 x 10 sparse Matrix of class "dfm"
      features
docs   12345 123456 1234567 12345678 54321 54432 76543 11234 12234 123345
  col1     1      1       1        1     0     0     0     0     0      0
  col2     1      0       0        0     1     1     1     0     0      0
  col3     0      0       1        0     0     0     0     1     1      1
  col4     1      0       0        0     1     1     1     0     0      0
```

I hope this helps !

Comment: Hi, I ran this but I am having trouble exmaning (to get the output you show). I have tried (DocTerm@i and others but I am just seeing a bunch of lists)

Comment: To me it works perfectly. Check your R version. That might cause the trouble. To extract staff, I hope this other question might help you out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53540787/finding-cosine-similarity-of-documents-and-their-removal-from-r-dataframe/53542848#53542848

Comment: Hmmm. This case works fine,however, when applied to larger scale (unique ids=75000) the matrix is not available. Im going to try with significantly larger sample to see if it repeats