# dplyr Create new boolean variable from any_vars() filter condition

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to create a boolean variable based on a condition of multiple variables. As shown in the second answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28233561/finding-rows-containing-a-value-or-values-in-any-column), one can filter based on many conditions across a number of columns:

```r
 mtcars %>% filter_at(vars(starts_with("d"),starts_with("c")), any_vars(. %in% c(4)))
```

I would like to do something like

```r
test <- mtcars %>% mutate(has.4 = any_vars(vars(starts_with("d"),starts_with("c")) %in% c(4)))
```

but this of course does not work and gives ``` Error: Column ``has.4`` is of unsupported type quoted call ```.

The `filter_at()` call is already creating the boolean with which to subset the data on. How can I pipe that output into a new variable, and keep all rows?

Also, I only want to create one new column, so `mutate_at()` and `mutate_if()` don't seem to be the right calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the `starts_with`, here an option is `matches`

```
library(dplyr)
out1 <- mtcars %>% 
            filter_at(vars(matches('^(d|c)')), any_vars(. %in% 4))
```

---

If we need a column, we can create the condition with `rowSums`

```
out2 <- mtcars %>%
           mutate(has.4 = rowSums(select(., matches("^(d|c)")) == 4) > 0)

identical(out1, out2 %>%
                        filter(has.4) %>%
                         select(-has.4))
#[1] TRUE
```