# Finding partial match strings in any column in a dataframe in R

Tags: r, apply

I have a dataframe;

```
vessel<-c(letters[1:4])
type<-c("Fishery Vessel","NA","NA","Cargo")
class<-c("NA","FISHING","NA","CARGO")
status<-c("NA", "NA", "Engaged in Fishing", "Underway")
df<-data.frame(vessel,type, class, status)

vessel           type   class             status
1      a Fishery Vessel      NA                 NA
2      b             NA FISHING                 NA
3      c             NA      NA Engaged in Fishing
4      d          Cargo   CARGO           Underway
```

I would like to subset the df to contain only those rows relating to fishing (ie rows 1:3) so that means to me doing something like;

```
df.sub<-subset(grep("FISH", df) | grep("Fish", df))
```

But this doesn't work.  I've been trialing `apply` (such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28233561/finding-rows-containing-a-value-or-values-in-any-column) question) or partial string matching using `grep` (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13043928/selecting-data-frame-rows-based-on-partial-string-match-in-a-column) question) but I can't seem to pull it all together.

Grateful for any help. My data is 10s of columns and up to a million rows, so trying my best to avoid loops if possible but maybe that's the only way?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `apply()` you could compute an index based on your string `fish` and then subset. The way to compute `Index` is obtaining the sum of those values which match with `fish` using `grepl()`. You can enable `ignore.case = T` in order to avoid issues with upper or lower case text. When the index is greater or equal to 1 then any match occurred so you can make the subset. Here the code:

```
#Data
vessel<-c(letters[1:4])
type<-c("Fishery Vessel","NA","NA","Cargo")
class<-c("NA","FISHING","NA","CARGO")
status<-c("NA", "NA", "Engaged in Fishing", "Underway")
df<-data.frame(vessel,type, class, status,stringsAsFactors = F)
#Subset
#Create an index with apply
df$Index <- apply(df[1:4],1,function(x) sum(grepl('fish',x,ignore.case = T)))
#Filter
df.sub<-subset(df,Index>=1)
```

Output:

```
  vessel           type   class             status Index
1      a Fishery Vessel      NA                 NA     1
2      b             NA FISHING                 NA     1
3      c             NA      NA Engaged in Fishing     1
```

Comment: that's worked and is quite fast for my data, many thanks!

Comment: by the way, why did you add the 'stringsAsFactors=F' when creating the data.frame?  Does apply or grepl not work for factors?

Comment: @user2175481 You are right, factors are coded as numbers so `grepl()` won't work. In your case, you must use `grepl()` for testing a condition over a string. Then, it is preferred having variables as text. If that explanation was not clear enough let me know!

Answer (score 1):

Another option you can try

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
  filter_all(any_vars(str_detect(., regex("fish", ignore_case =TRUE))))
#   vessel           type   class             status
# 1      a Fishery Vessel      NA                 NA
# 2      b             NA FISHING                 NA
# 3      c             NA      NA Engaged in Fishing
```

Comment: Thanks @Tho Vu - I'll try your suggestion too as I'd like to learn more dplyr.

Answer (score 0):

In `base R`, we can use vectorized option with `grepl` and `Reduce`

```
subset(df, Reduce(`|`, lapply(df[-1], grepl, pattern = 'fish', ignore.case = TRUE)))
#  vessel           type   class             status
#1      a Fishery Vessel      NA                 NA
#2      b             NA FISHING                 NA
#3      c             NA      NA Engaged in Fishing
```